# resize window when keyboard displayed on mobile phone

Tags: html, css, mobile

I develop a mobile version of the site. In accordance with the principles of responsive design block size is a percentage.

html, body{
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%
}

What or when the input box has focus virtual keyboard appears. Since the decreased height of the screen, the size of the other units also decreased (as indicated in percentage of body). How can I avoid this? How can I avoid this? Ie block height must be calculated from the height of the device screen. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a spesific reason for having `height: 100%`? You only need the layout to adapt responsively to the width of the screen while height could very well be `height:auto;`

Comment: Height have to be 100%. Otherwise it is impossible to specify the height of objects relative to other body (in percent).

Comment: My question (which should rather be in a comment, but i don't have privilegies :/), is why would you need to? Wouldn't you want your objects to scale downwards based on the content you put in them rather than have height based on set values? Perhaps someone will come along with a better answer, but in the meantime could you show me a scenario in JSFiddle where content would need preset heights?

Comment: Need to mark up the following page. I do not know how to do it for mobile devices, without specifying all percentage (responsive web design)


[1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/bkXmc.png

Comment: I know for a fact that you could do this with some clever use of `padding:xx%;margin:xx%;` on the items in your flow. Props on the design btw, looks wicked :) There might be easier solutions to your problem (allowing for `height: 100%`, but i'm not aware of any. sorry.